# Where can I find mobile software for Fischer random chess?

Tags: software, chess-variants, chess960

Fischer had a chess variation (chess960) but I cannot find any mobile app to play it.

Does anyone knows where I can get the best software (if possible free or cheap) to play it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of websites and tools listed on the [Chess960 wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess960#Chess960.2C_servers_tools_and_software). Scroll to the bottom for the complete list. These should all be playable on your mobile device.

- http://en.lichess.org/
- http://www.chesshotel.com/play-random-chess.php
- http://www.mychess.de/

Comment: There is also Chess.com's free mobile software, which allows for playing Chess960 as correspondence chess. This may or may not be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

2012 there was chesscube i think...oh wait i think i remember in 2014 they didn't have 9LX in their app. RIP chessube

2021 this is very moot of course. lichess, chessdotcom, chessvision (using lichess), etc

Answer (score 0):

If you use iOS there’s Chess Studio from AppStore which it’s great and have the 960 board positions to play against machine! Which is Stockfish!